# Value of Column Name DataGridView

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ado.net, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and i'm developing a windows form. Right now I'm using a data grid view and i want to write some functions that would allow you to automaticlly edit the datagrid by just changing the text in the Datagrid view. Right now, I am able to get the actual value but I need the value of the column in order to use it as a parameter when i use ADO.net here's what my code looks like now

```
    private void dgv_DataLookup_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr;
        dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to edit this field?", "Edit Cell", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            DataGridViewCell editItemCell = dgv_DataLookup[dgv_DataLookup.CurrentCell.RowIndex, dgv_DataLookup.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex];
            string editItem = editItemCell.Value.ToString();


        }
    }
```

this here gets me the value of the current cell that is currently selected. I tried doing something like this

DataGridViewColumns columnCells = dgv_DataLookup.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Value.ToString()... something that would represent this but actual code. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understand you want to edit the value within a field, you can choose the value in this way.

```
      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to edit this field?",Application.ProductName.ToString(),MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)== DialogResult.Yes) 
        {
            string editItem = this.dataGridView1.Rows[this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells["NameField"].Value.ToString();                
        }
    }
```

Bye

Comment: correct i want to edit an item in the field but I want to transfer the update to my database as well using ADO.net this is an update button